# image from server side to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
var expoImage: [String] = []
```

i have get the value from mySQL Database and all its coming and one of them is URL link for image that and its save in the same web host

```
func loadData() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.q8-9ndo5aan.com/kuwaitExpoApps/script/getExpo.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    // modify the request as necessary, if necessary

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

            if error != nil {
                // Display an alert message

                print(error)

                return
            }

            do {

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? [[String:AnyObject]]


                if (json != nil) {

                    for item in json! {

                self.expoImage.append((item["expoImage"] as? String)!)

                        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()

                    }

                    // Display an alert message


                } else {

                    // Display an alert message
                    let userMessage = "Could not fetch Value"
                    print(userMessage)

                }



            } catch  {

                print(error)

            }

        })

    }).resume()


}
```

and when i print in console of Xcode the link displayed well , but my problem is did not displayed the image in the UICollectionView

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let myCell: myCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        let imageString = self.expoImage[indexPath.row]
        let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageString)
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            if(imageData != nil) {

                myCell.expoImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                myCell.expoImageBack.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            }

        });

    });

    return myCell

}
```

any one have ideas for that

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the new App Transport Security, which blocks all the non-HTTPS requests. You link may be a regular HTTP link, causing it to return 'nil'. If this is the case then you need to modify your app's info.plist. Make sure your info.plist looks something like this -

[image]

Comment: its already same but the error that coming " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value "

Comment: That means that some of your image files are null, and as i can see in your code you are force unwrapping the values. 
My guess is that you get the crash here: 
                myCell.expoImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                myCell.expoImageBack.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
because they are still not downloaded from let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)

Comment: Try working with SDWebImage library who not only downloads the image, but also caches it.

Comment: Maybe try something like this?

`let myImage =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl))
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                myCell.expoImage.image = myImage
}`

Comment: ahh , it's going well that because that URL image their is a space that way they give nil , and that mean Xcode cant converted and add 20% when try open an URL having a space :s

Comment: you can resolve that by doing `let urlStr: String = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`